# How does emit work?

Tags: solidity

In the following example from the Solidity documentation, what does `emit` do?

```
highestBidder = msg.sender;
highestBid = msg.value;
emit HighestBidIncreased(msg.sender, msg.value);
```

Comment: It means "when this transaction is written into the blockchain, write alongside it a `HighestBidIncreased` event with the current values of `msg.sender` and `msg.value`".

Answer (score 5):

Emit keyword is used to emit an event in solidity, which can be read by the client in Dapp.

Event in solidity is to used to log the transactions happening in the blockchain.

Reference:  https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#events